# How can i import all the tables because it doesnt import all the tables in phpmyadmin. Some tables are missing

Tags: php

I cant find out whats wrong with my code in importing database. It doesnt import all the tables. some are missing. How can I modify my code?

```
<?php 
$message = '';
if(isset($_POST["import"]))
{
if($_FILES["database"]["name"] != '')
{
$array = explode(".", $_FILES["database"]["name"]);
$extension = end($array);
if($extension == 'sql')
{
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "db_ihk");
$output = '';
$count = 0;
$file_data = file($_FILES["database"]["tmp_name"]);
foreach($file_data as $row)
{
$start_character = substr(trim($row), 0, 2);
if($start_character != '--' || $start_character != '/*' || 
$start_character != '//' || $row != '')
{
 $output = $output . $row;
 $end_character = substr(trim($row), -1, 1);
 if($end_character == ';')
 {
  if(!mysqli_query($connect, $output))
  {
   $count++;
  }
  $output = '';
 }
}
}
if($count > 0)
{
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Database already exists!');
```

Comment: Need to add your code, how do we know?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i have already added my code above.

Comment: What are the names of the table missing and what are the tables imported? Maybe there is a pattern.

Comment: What does each line in your input files look like?

Answer (score 0):

`SET autocommit=0 ; source file_path ;COMMIT;`

change your file path with file_path and run on mysql terminal